# Rails errors causing Apache / Passanger internal server errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Ok I thought I was close to getting passenger and Apache working. I notice that some gem files were not installed after navigating to the url to see if my rails app was working. Passanger error page let me know what gems were missing so I got them installed.

Now going to the URL I get a 500 Apache internal error page with no helpful info so I checked out the log file on the server and here is what I see.

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/mydirectory/dev/vb/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. $
Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
[Tue Dec 07 20:12:17 2010] [error] [client 64.58.208.22] Premature end of script headers:
[ pid=20653 thr=140618873321280 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:816 time=2010-12-07 20:12:17.617 ]: The backend application (proce$
Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
[Tue Dec 07 20:12:43 2010] [error] [client 64.58.208.22] Premature end of script headers:


Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
[Tue Dec 07 20:13:25 2010] [error] [client 64.58.208.22] Premature end of script headers:
[ pid=21932 thr=140618873321280 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:816 time=2010-12-07 20:13:25.168 ]: The backend application (proce$
Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
[Tue Dec 07 20:13:31 2010] [error] [client 64.58.208.22] Premature end of script headers:
[ pid=20623 thr=140618873321280 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:816 time=2010-12-07 20:13:31.266 ]: The backend application (proce$
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/mydirectory/dev/vb/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. $
Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
[Tue Dec 07 20:24:56 2010] [error] [client 64.58.208.22] Premature end of script headers:
[ pid=20622 thr=140618873321280 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:816 time=2010-12-07 20:24:56.442 ]: The backend application (proce$
Rack: /home/mydirectory/dev/vb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@prodset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite$
```

anyone have any suggestions on what I should look at next. I have tried running bundler and also using rvm to install sqlite3 and I still have the same issue.

thanks again for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked the suggestion on the first line of the error log?

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/mydirectory/dev/vb/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666.
```

Comment: yep ... when I looked there was not a production.log so I created one and made sure to set the permissions